# Firebase authentication problem in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

i have a problem with firebase authentication in flutter.
Registration is successful, when i try to log in, after press login button, i have this error

> W/Firestore(31652): (21.3.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(users/<...UID...>) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
>
> I/flutter (31652): PlatformException(Error performing get, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., null)

Login button code is:

```
child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Login", style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontFamily: 'MontserratBold',
            ),
            ),
            elevation: 5.0,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
            textColor: Colors.black,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            onPressed: () {
              if (_loginFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
                FirebaseAuth.instance
                    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                    email: emailInputController.text,
                    password: pwdInputController.text)
                    .then((currentUser) => Firestore.instance
                    .collection("users")
                    .document(currentUser.user.uid)
                    .get()
                    .then((DocumentSnapshot result) =>
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => HomePage(
                              uid: currentUser.user.uid,
                            ))))
                    .catchError((err) => print(err)))
                    .catchError((err) => print(err));
              }
            },
          ),
```

I also read that a possible solution is to change permissions in firebase, but in that case i allow any users to write and read or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you allow read and write in firebase database rules-

[image: Firebase configuration]

Comment: ok, but maybe it's not a secure solution. I've tryed to use "allow read, write: if request.auth != null" and works but is the best solution ? secure enough ?

Comment: @luc Looking at [this Firestore Security link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure) you seem to be on the right track. For a specified document (you can different rules for different documents in firestore) configure your rules for read and write to how you want it.